# Jquery >> PHP >> cURL and browser refresh

Tags: php, jquery, post, curl, transactions

I have a problem with one website i wrote a few weeks ago. 
my website communicates with another website_2 via API hosted on website_2

the curl operation is requested via Query POST to a PHP file. 
if for some reason the operation took a longer time (which i can't determine the reason for) and the user hits refresh.. the command sent to the API is done yet my server doesn't get any result so can't log or do anything with that result.. 
is there a way to preserve the integrity of such transaction? 
below is my code and i still get FAILED no matter what the result was on website_2

```
 function doCommit($url_)
 {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera/9.23 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
    $commit = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(!curl_exec($ch))
    {
    $ERROR="<Transaction>
          <Result>Failed</Result>
          <Reason>Operation Timed Out</Reason>
        </Transaction>";
    $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($ERROR);
    return $oXML;
    }
    else{
    $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($commit);
    return $oXML;
    }
    // return $oXML->Reason;
}
```

Comment: What should happen if website_2 is down for example? Did you set a timeout in your curl request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl parameters to solve your problem setting a "request timeout":

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - Sets The number of seconds to wait before a curl individual function timeouts.

CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - Sets the maximum time before curl connection timeouts.

...and then you could return a text if curl_exec fails:

```
if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
{
    echo 'ERROR: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by the following code

```
function doCommit($url_)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera/9.23 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    $commit = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch) == 0)
    {
    $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($commit);
    return $oXML;
    }
    else{
    $ERROR="<Transaction>
          <Result>Failed</Result>
          <Reason>Operation Timed Out</Reason>
        </Transaction>";
    $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($ERROR);
    return $oXML;
    }
    // return $oXML->Reason;
}
```